# trying to use a frame in another frame but from two different classes

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe

The first class contains the main and an actionListener, when triggerd, it should call the frame from the second class, if possible.

```
public class IntelliJFrame{
  public IntelliJFrame(){

  }
```

This is the second Class with the desired Frame i would like to use in the First Class.

```
public class TableFrameforestudent extends JFrame {
}
public TableFrameforestudent() {
}
```

Comment: This is bad program design -- see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) to see why. Also, it is a fairly common question, and in the future you'll want to search this site to look for duplicates before asking a question that has likely been commonly asked before.

Comment: Sorry, aou helped me a lot anyway so Thanks :)